# What is the mean of true love according to the buddhism?

Tags: love

I really need to know what is the mean of true love according to Buddhism?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think this is a duplicate of other questions, which might already have good answers -- see also [Posts containing 'love'](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=love)

Comment: @ChrisW Sure I will check.Thank you